# How to cache a reactive publisher like Observable?

Tags: caching, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, project-reactor

I'm trying to understand what happens if I cache the result of a method returning a cold Observable? The flow has not been materialized yet, so what does the cache actually contain? I tried to find out using Hazelcast and Spring Boot but couldn't get the cache working.

**Edit**:
When I say cache not working, I am speaking based on what I see from Hazelcast Management Center. Depending on the cache config (I tried many things), either the cache shows up but no entries, or the cache doesn't show up at all.

Example:

```
@javax.cache.annotation.CacheResult
Observable<Integer> random() {
    // Do I get a new number every time?
    return Observable.just(new Random().nextInt());
}
```

Comment: What does "couldn't get the cache working" mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity See edit.

Answer (score 1):

From rx-java wiki (source [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure)):

> A cold Observable emits a particular sequence of items, but can begin
>   emitting this sequence when its Observer finds it to be convenient,
>   and at whatever rate the Observer desires, without disrupting the
>   integrity of the sequence. For example if you convert a static
>   Iterable into an Observable, that Observable will emit the same
>   sequence of items no matter when it is later subscribed to or how
>   frequently those items are observed. Examples of items emitted by a
>   cold Observable might include the results of a database query, file
>   retrieval, or web request.

With cold `Observable`, like your example, the request is done at subscribe time, for each subscriber. Even without cache, if you subscribe twice to the same `Observable`, the request will occur twice. The `Observable` is not bound to a specific stream. `Observable` is just a contract describing how to access data.

Caching the result of a method returning an `Observable` is I think somewhat similar to storing the result to a local property; you just avoid to recreate the `Observable` object again later. But just the 'getter', not the data.

rx-java give some tools to achieve caching by it's own. You could have a look to [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) or [ConnectableObservable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Connectable-Observable-Operators).

Comment: So, the crux of your answer is that `Observable` can't be cached using traditional methods. Did I get that right?

Comment: I don't know all those methods but most of them will cache the Observable but not the stream going through it, yes.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar - The observable can be cached normally, but the observable isn't the same as the values produced by the observable. That only happens when you have an observer and a subscription.

Comment: I appreciate the answer and hence upvoted it, but it didn't provide me with anything that I didn't already know. The various `cache*` methods on `Observable` basically replay the sequence, and in RxJava 1.x don't even have a TTL (project reactor does). There's no concept of a key either; like I said, it's essentially replaying the sequence, which is not what traditional key and TTL based caching does.